# Android emulator, cannot access dev tools menu

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to debug my android app in my emulator. I am using `ctrl + m` but nothing happens.

I have published my app using `Expo`, but my dev tools menu has disappeared.

`React-native` states my current mode is `development`, yet my console states `Running app on Android SDK built for x86 in production mode`

How do I rebuild in `development` so I can debug?

Comment: `ctrl + m` only acts as the old physical menu key. It'll only work if your app has a `...` menu in the top-right corner of your activity. What Dev Tools menu are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: I need to debug my app in chrome dev tools, `enable remote debugging`

Comment: I get the message `Running app on Android SDK built for x86 in production mode` how can I go back to developer mode?